# How to prove that a given basis spans a certain subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, if I am given three linearly independent $3 \times 3$ matrices. How would I go about proving that they span, say the set containing all skew symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices?

Thanks for any help. Linear algebra does my head in.

Comment: The subspace of skew symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices has dimension $3$. You can show this by exhibiting the basis formed by matrices that have zeros everywhere, except for position $i,j$ and $j,i$ for $i\neq j$ where it has $\pm1$. Then, just showing tha tyour system of vectors are skew symmetric is enough. Since you know that they are linearly independent, they will generate the space.

Comment: @LASERBEARASSAULTUNIT Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we can consider the four matrices as 9-by-1 vectors and perform a RREF or solve the system $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=w$.

In this case note that the subspace of skew symmetric matrices has dimension 6.